# .NET threading solution for long queries

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

**Senerio**

We have a C# .Net Web Application that records incidents. An external database needs to be queried when an incident is approved by a supervisor. The queries to this external database are sometimes taking a while to run. This lag is experienced through the browser.

**Possible Solution**

I want to use threading to eliminate the simulated hang to the browser. I have used the `Thread` class before and heard about `ThreadPool`. But, I just found `BackgroundWorker` in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/c-how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread).

[MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient solution.

**Is `BackgroundWorker` the way to go when handling long running queries?**

**What happens when 2 or more `BackgroundWorker` processes are ran simultaneously? Is it handled like a pool?**

Comment: Sorry is this a desktop application or web application?

Comment: @Eddie: C# doesn't support threads. You're asking about the .NET Framework, aren't you?

Comment: @John C# DOES support threading!

Comment: The BackgroundWoker uses the .Net ThreadPool under the covers, so if you use two background workers, it's just like calling threadpool.queueuserworkitem twice.

Comment: @Eddie Careful.  John is a stickler for that distinction.  C# itself doesn't have a threading.  The .net framework (meaning the `Thread` class) provides threading support.

Comment: Well, if we're going to be sticklers :)... c# does not offer the ability to create a thread (that's in the .net runtime), the language DOES support threading (hence the lock statement). (and we might say, yes but that's just a wrapper around a Monitor, but it's still a statement that is recognized by the c# compiler, and it's only purpose is to support threading).  If we're going to be distinctive :)

Comment: @JMarsch: I apologize. I forgot about the `lock` statement. I should have said that C# does not support the creation or management of threads, and only permits their control through the `lock` statement.

Comment: @Jason: the reason I'm a stickler here is that C# is not the only .NET language! VB.NET and F# are .NET languages from Microsoft that have precisely the same threading support as C# (none). All three depend on the .NET Framework for threading, and to exactly the same degree.

Comment: Yes, project is a C# .Net web application.

Comment: @John Saunders: Thanks for the edits. Was in a rush when posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **BackgroundWorker** can significantly simplify your threading code for long-running operations.  The key is registering for the **[DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork(v=VS.100).aspx)**, **[ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=VS.100).aspx)**, and **[RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz2ts075(v=VS.100).aspx)** events.  These help you avoid having to have a bunch of synchronization objects passed back and forth with the thread to try to determine the progress of the operation.

Also, I believe the progress events are called on the UI thread, avoiding the need for calls to **Control.Invoke** to update your UI.

To answer your last question, yes, threads are allocated from the .NET thread pool, so you while you may instantiate as many BackgroundWorker objects as you'd like, you can only run as many concurrent operations as the thread pool will allow.

Comment: That's right - the progress and completed events are marshaled to the UI thread (well, whatever the current thread synchronization context says to do, but for winforms/wpf that's the UI thread) so you don't have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 4 (or can use the TPL backport from the Rx Framework), then one nice option is to use a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) created with the [LongRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) hint.

This provides many options difficult to accomplish via the ThreadPool or BackgroundWorker, including allowing for continuations to be specified at creation time, as well as allowing for clean cancellation and exception/error handling.

Comment: Currently, built for .Net 3.5.

Comment: I do like the typed return value for Task<TResult> though. Does beat out (object)DoWorkEventArgs.Result in BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Eddie: You can use the Rx Framework to get the TPL for .NET 3.5sp1.  It's a much, much cleaner API than previous threading models, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I had ran in similar situation with long running queries. I used the asynchronous invoke provided by delegates. You can use the BeginInvoke method of the delegate.

Comment: Both the asynchronous delegate invoking, and the background worker use the ThreadPool under the covers. If it's a simple background process that needs to run, and you don't need the added complexity of IAsyncResult, BackgroundWorker is a better choice IMO.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWrokerks are just like any other threads, accept they can be killed or quit, w/out exiting the main thread and your application.

ThreadPool uses a pool of BackgroundWorkers. It is the preferred way of most multi threading scenarios because .net manages threads for you, and it re-uses them instead of creating new ones as needed which is a expensive process.

Such threading scenarios are great for processor intensive code.

For something like a query which happens externally, you also have the option of asynchronous data access. You can hand off the query request, and give it the name of your callback method, which will be called when query is finished and than do something with the result (i.e. update UI status or display returned data)..

.Net has inbuilt support for asynchronous data querying
http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/26747