# MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 shows 3 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

When I run the following code:

```
public static double SumRootN(int root)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        result += Math.Exp(Math.Log(i) / root);
    }
    return result;
}

static void Main()
{
    ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2; // -1 is for unlimited. 1 is for sequential. 

    try
    {
        Parallel.For(
                0,
                9,
                options,
                (i) =>
        {
            var result = SumRootN(i);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread={0}, root {0} : {1} ",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i, result);
        });
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Parallel.For has thrown the following (unexpected) exception:\n{0}", e);
    }
}
```

I see that the output is:

[image: Screenshot]

There are 3 thread Ids here, but I have specified that the `MaxDegreeOFParallelism` is only 2. So why is there 3 threads doing the work instead of 2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538452/what-does-maxdegreeofparallelism-do

Comment: I don't think it's about 'which' threads, I think it's only about how many simultaneously. So I don't expect it to guarantee ,'reusing' threads.

Comment: So you're saying that at any one time only 2 threads will be running, and that the id is irrelevant?

Answer (score 4):

Quote from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx

By default, For and ForEach will utilize however many threads the underlying scheduler provides, so changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from the default only limits how many concurrent tasks will be used.

Translation: only 2 threads will be running at any given moment, but more (or even less) than 2 may be used out of the thread pool. You can test this with another writeline at the start of the task, you'll see that no 3 threads will enter concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

The [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) defines the maximum concurrent invocations of the `body` delegate. It doesn't define the maximum number of individual threads that might be involved in the `body` invocations. All the `Parallel` APIs do their work by creating tasks and executing them on the specified [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler). The default `TaskScheduler` is the [`TaskScheduler.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default), which schedules the execution of the tasks on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). The `ThreadPool` executes the tasks on any of the threads that are currently available in the pool. So the behavior that you observe is dominated by the behavior of the `ThreadPool`, and the behavior of the `ThreadPool` is not documented in details.

As an experiment you could configure the `Parallel.For` with a custom `TaskScheduler` that executes each task on a dedicated thread, instead of the `ThreadPool`. You can find an implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570579/is-it-possible-always-to-force-a-new-thread-with-task/68929857#68929857). You would see an even greater variability on thread IDs than in your original experiment.