# How to use Task.WhenAll to run 2 calculations at once

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel-processing, task

I'm trying to learn how to use async tasks and am really struggling just to get a simple example working. I provide a very simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve below.

```
public void Calculate()
{
    int a1 = 1;
    int a2 = 2;
    int b1 = 3;
    int b2 = 4;
    int c3 = 5;
    int c4 = 6;
    int c5 = 7;
    int c6 = 8;
    int c7 = 9;

    // Do next 2 lines in parallel
    int rank1 = Evaluate(a1, a2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7);
    int rank2 = Evaluate(b1, b2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7);

    // wait for above 2 lines and use values to get result
    int result = EvaluateOutcome(rank1, rank2);
}

public static int Evaluate(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7)
{
    // do something complicated and return value - simulate here with random number
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.Next(0,10);
}

public static int EvaluateOutcome(int rank1, int rank2)
{
    return rank1 * rank2;
}
```

Calculating `rank1` and `rank2` is a long process in my real code but the calculations are independent of each other. I'd like to try to run both calculations at once to hopefully half the processing time. I need to await both calculations completing prior to calculating result.

I think I should be able to do something like:

```
private async Task Evaluate(int a1, int a2, int b1, int b2, int c3, int c4, int c5, int c6, int c7)
{
    Task task1 = Evaluate(a1, a2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7);
    Task task2 = Evaluate(b1, b2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7);

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

But this does not compile and I'm unsure how to get the results from the Task and put them into my `rank1` and `rank2` int variables. I think this should be incredibly simple but I can't find a clear example to follow. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `Task.Run()` ... Add `static Task<int> EvaluateAsync(int i1, ...) => Task.Run((i1, ..). => Evaluate(i1,...);` then `Task<int> task1 = EvaluateAsync(a1, ...);` and then after `await Task.WhenAll` you can get `task1.Result` as `rank1` similar stuff with `task2`

Comment: That sounds good Selvin. I'd really appreciate if you could put the full code in an answer. Many thanks

Comment: Or better: a list of parameters sets, and pass it to `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: could you show me how please charlie

Comment: @Selvin it would be great if you could help with the detail of the code you suggested. I think thats the answer but I'm unable to figure it out myself TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method to offload each calculation to a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread, and the [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall) method in order to block the current thread until the two calculations are complete:

```
Task<int> task1 = Task.Run(() => Evaluate(a1, a2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7));
Task<int> task2 = Task.Run(() => Evaluate(b1, b2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7));

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

int rank1 = task1.Result;
int rank2 = task2.Result;
```

A more efficient alternative is to use the [`Parallel.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke) method. The core difference is that the current thread will participate in the work too, by doing one of the two calculations. So only one additional thread (from the `ThreadPool`) will be used:

```
int rank1 = default;
int rank2 = default;

var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Parallel.Invoke(parallelOptions,
    () => rank1 = Evaluate(a1, a2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7),
    () => rank2 = Evaluate(b1, b2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7)
);
```

The documentation of the `Parallel.Invoke` is a bit confusing, by stating that it *executes each of the provided actions, **possibly** in parallel*. Don't worry. The only case that the calculations will not happen in parallel is if the `ThreadPool` is saturated. In which case the first approach (`Task.Run`+`Task.WaitAll`) will fail to parallelize the calculations too, while contributing even more to the saturation of the pool. If you want to take the `ThreadPool` out of the equation, you could pass a custom [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) with the [`ParallelOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions), that executes the tasks on a dedicated thread per task, like the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570579/is-it-possible-always-to-force-a-new-thread-with-task/68929857#68929857). Or use the [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) flag.

Comment: Thanks Theodor. With the second approach int result = EvaluateOutcome(rank1, rank2); fails to compile when placed after the Parallell Invoke due to unassigned rank1,rank2. Is it OK just to initialise each to zero where you declared them?

Comment: Strangely, both approaches makes my code run about 15x slower. Any thoughts why that might be?

Comment: @SteveW yeap, the variables must be initialized for the `Parallel.Invoke` version to compile. It is safe to initialize them in this example, but it certainly makes the code less robust. Future modifications could introduce bugs more easily. I don't know how it can be robustified in this aspect honestly.

Comment: @SteveW as for the parallel version being slower, it's probably because the overall work is too lightweight. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036120/parallel-foreach-slower-than-foreach "Parallel.ForEach Slower than ForEach") out for more details.