# Updating different properties of same object in Parallel.Invoke is thread-safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, multitasking, parallel.invoke

I'm working with a class which contains complex properties. Each of these properties are computed through different methods. I'm using `Parallel.Invoke` to update different properties of the same object. Will this cause any issue to the object ?

```
// sample class definition. I've simplified the example by using 'object' type
// for complex types. 
public class TestResult
{
     public object Property1;

     public object Property2;

     public object Property3;
}

// here we populate an object. We are processing it parallelly because each method
// takes some considerable amount of time. 
var testResult = new TestResult();
Parallel.Invoke(
() =>
{
       testResult.Property1 = GetProperty1Value();
},
() =>
{
       testResult.Property2 = GetProperty2Value();
},
() =>
{
       testResult.Property3 = GetProperty3Value();
});
```

Will the above code cause ANY issues to `testResult` object?

Note: I've tested this part of code. Doesn't seem to cause any issues. As far as I know, since different properties are getting worked upon in different tasks, this shouldn't been an issue. I couldn't find any documentation around this. I wanted to confirm this behavior hence asking this question.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to use Task.WhenAll to run 2 calculations at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68924697/how-to-use-task-whenall-to-run-2-calculations-at-once)

Comment: The answer is `yes, lots of issues`. This exact snippet won't has threading issues because it's trivial. Nothing prevents any of the delegates from trying to modify multiple properties, or trying to use property values that were modified by another delegate.

Comment: could you please explain what issues are there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost it should be mentioned that the `Property1`, `Property2` and `Property3` in your example are technically called [*fields*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), not [*properties*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Your example is perfectly safe regarding the integrity of the `TestResult` instance, after the `Parallel.Invoke` operation has successfully completed.
All of its fields will be initialized, and their values [will be visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581848/memory-barrier-generators) by the current thread (but not necessarily visible by other threads that were already running before the completion of the `Parallel.Invoke`).

On the other hand if the `Parallel.Invoke` fails, then the `TestResult` instance may end up being partially initialized.

If the `Property1`, `Property2` and `Property3` were actually [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), then the thread-safety of your code would depend on the code running behind the `set` accessors of those properties. In case this code was trivial, like `set { _property1 = value; }`, then again your code would be safe.

As a side note, you are advised to configure the `Parallel.Invoke` operation with a reasonable `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. Otherwise you'll get the default behavior of the `Parallel` class, which is to [saturate the `ThreadPool`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261010/multiple-parallel-foreach-loops-in-net/66263583#66263583).

```
TestResult testResult = new();

Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions()
{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
    () => testResult.Property1 = GetProperty1Value(),
    () => testResult.Property2 = GetProperty2Value(),
    () => testResult.Property3 = GetProperty3Value()
);
```

---

**Alternative:** In case you are wondering how you could initialize a `TestResult` instance without relying on closures and side-effects, here is
one way to do it:

```
var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(
    TaskScheduler.Default, Environment.ProcessorCount).ConcurrentScheduler);

var task1 = taskFactory.StartNew(() => GetProperty1Value());
var task2 = taskFactory.StartNew(() => GetProperty2Value());
var task3 = taskFactory.StartNew(() => GetProperty3Value());

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);

TestResult testResult = new()
{
    Property1 = task1.Result,
    Property2 = task2.Result,
    Property3 = task3.Result,
};
```

The values of the properties are stored temporarily in the individual `Task` objects, and finally they are assigned to the properties, on the current thread, after the completion of all tasks. So this approach eliminates all thread-safety considerations regarding the integrity of the constructed `TestResult` instance.

But there is a disadvantage: The `Parallel.Invoke` utilizes the current thread, and invokes some of the actions on it too. On the contrary the `Task.WaitAll` approach will wastefully block the current thread, letting the `ThreadPool` do all the work.

---

**Just for fun**: I tried to write an `ObjectInitializer` tool that should be able to calculate the properties of an object in parallel, and then assign the value of each property sequentially (thread-safely), without having to manage manually a bunch of scattered `Task` variables. This is the API I came up with:

```
var initializer = new ObjectInitializer<TestResult>();
initializer.Add(() => GetProperty1Value(), (x, v) => x.Property1 = v);
initializer.Add(() => GetProperty2Value(), (x, v) => x.Property2 = v);
initializer.Add(() => GetProperty3Value(), (x, v) => x.Property3 = v);
TestResult testResult = initializer.RunParallel(degreeOfParallelism: 2);
```

Not very pretty, but at least it is concise. The `Add` method adds the metadata for one property, and the `RunParallel` does the parallel and sequential work. Here is the implementation:

```
public class ObjectInitializer<TObject> where TObject : new()
{
    private readonly List<Func<Action<TObject>>> _functions = new();

    public void Add<TProperty>(Func<TProperty> calculate,
        Action<TObject, TProperty> update)
    {
        _functions.Add(() =>
        {
            TProperty value = calculate();
            return source => update(source, value);
        });
    }

    public TObject RunParallel(int degreeOfParallelism)
    {
        TObject instance = new();
        _functions
            .AsParallel()
            .AsOrdered()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(degreeOfParallelism)
            .Select(func => func())
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(action => action(instance));
        return instance;
    }
}
```

It uses [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) instead of the `Parallel` class.

Would I use it? Probably not. Mostly because the need for initializing an object in parallel doesn't come very often, and having to maintain so obscure code for such rare occasions seems like overkill. I would probably go with the dirty and side-effecty `Parallel.Invoke` approach instead. :-)

Comment: Incisive answer. can you please clarify when Paralle.Invoke will fail ? I thought ALL the actions will be executed regardless whether an action had run into exception. it will be great if you can point me to the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @SRIDHARAN. Actually you are right. All `Action`s passed to the `Parallel.Invoke` are invoked no matter what. I was pretty confident that all methods of the `Parallel` class would have the same behavior, but apparently the `Parallel.Invoke` is a different beast. I am a bit disappointed to be honest, because I consider the fail-fast strategy a very desirable feature for a tool that facilitates parallelism. On the other hand this behavior can be enforced simply by not using the `Parallel.Invoke`, and using the `Parallel.ForEach` instead. So it's not a biggie really.

Comment: @SRIDHARAN I added one more approach. It's not very practical, but at least you might find it entertaining. :-)

Comment: looks good. bit of an overkill but as you mentioned it justifies "just for fun" :D Thanks!