# How to pass values from another thread to GUI for illustrate progress in C#?

Tags: multithreading

I have a program that processes image files in a method with a loop which runs in one thread while GUI runs another thread. During the processing I would like to report progress to the GUI from the method where the processing is done.

This is what I have. Base Windows Form class with GUI events which is inherited by other Windows Form classes. Plus Base class with methods and properties which is inherited by other classes. The other classes represent image formats from different image management apps that I migrate into my app. So I simply select another app name from drop down menu and it opens appropriate GUI that allows me to select image source.

- Partial ClassA which contains all GUI events such as button click and label text.
- Partial ClassA2 which inherits from ClassA.
- Abstract ClassB which contains virtual method . Plus, property which I would like to use to report progress to the label.
- ClassB2 which inherits ClassB and uses the method and property from the inherited class. The method is overriden in ClassB
- Object ClassB is declared in ClassA and initialized in ClassA2 to ClassB2.
- In ClassA in the button click event I use BackGroundWorker object which raises DoWork event with an EventHandler which contains delegate parameter which wraps overriden method that processes files.  I got solution here
  [How do I run a simple bit of code in a new thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/c-sharp-how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread)

The method contains a property which is assigned a new value each time loop passes, I would like to grab that value and display it on GUI each time loop passes and changes it.

I tried to use some solution but getting exception Window Handle not created.
[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

```
string newText = "abc";
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
someLabel.Text = newText;
});
```

Also, I tried this but InvokeRequired property returns FALSE value

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52752/Updating-Your-Form-from-Another-Thread-without-Cre

Comment: I prefer to use the [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) (then just use `Send` and `Post`) - make sure to obtain the SC *from the UI thread*; the main UI Window should be created *first*. However, BGW already supports `ReportProgress` so ..

Comment: I made a small and very simple app just to test this solution http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52752/Updating-Your-Form-from-Another-Thread-without-Cre and it works.