# run external .exe under thread

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

I need to run an external exe "**embed.exe**" under my WPF project,

here's a snippet

```
ProcessStartInfo processInf = new ProcessStartInfo("embed.exe");
processInf.Arguments = string.Format(@"Some arguments");
processInf.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process run = Process.Start(processInf);
```

my problem is that it's block my UI,

is there a way to include **embed.exe** using a thread or any code that won't block the UI ?

Comment: Does it block till you close the other application (embed.exe)? I guess it only block until the process is being loaded.

Comment: Run it on  a new thread, line in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/c-sharp-how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread

Comment: it's block only while embed.exe is working

Comment: @Kuf  : how could i import embed.exe under the thread ?

Comment: You defined `processInf` and two lines below that you are using `compressProcessInfo`. Is that OK?

Comment: Starting a new process doesn't block the current process. Probably you are missing something here.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn sorry for that, Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

Try to put your previous snippet inside a method, then create a new thread and initialize it to that method.

here's how to make it
//hone code

```
private void EmbedMethod()
{
ProcessStartInfo processInf = new ProcessStartInfo("embed.exe");
processInf.Arguments = string.Format(@"Some arguments");
processInf.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process run = Process.Start(processInf);
}

Thread embedThread=new Thread(EmbedMethod);
embedThread.start();
```

Comment: i have a problem now, yes no UI block but after exiting the program the process is still running, how could i terminate it before program termination ?

Comment: well, i tried to set IsBackground property to true, but still working, the problem is that i created a new process inside a running thread, is there a way to terminate that too ?

Answer (score 0):

The process you started is running on its own thread, not the thread your application used to start it.

To terminate your embed.exe process you need to keep a reference to the Process started. In this case the run variable. To terminate the process call either:
run.CloseMainWindow() or run.Kill().
Kill forces a termination of the process, while CloseMainWindow only requests a termination.

Comment: how do i keep a reference to `run` process out of `EmbedMethod`??,,i found a way to locate that process by searching in `Process.GetProcesses();` list , is there any other way ?