# Is there a "Sleep" command?

Tags: c#

In a lot of languages, there's a

> wait(milliseconds)

or

> sleep(milliseconds)

command, that just makes your program not execute *any more* code until the sleep is up (this doesn't mean it **stops** the code that's running, it just pauses from running more. Is there a command like this in C#?

**Thread.Sleep(time) doesn't work, it pauses all code that is currently executing as well (basically freezes your program)**

Comment: FYI, doing this in the main GUI thread is a **extremely bad idea**! The UI will not respond when doing that which results in a horrible user experience.

Comment: There are search engines for such question... "C# Sleep" will give you something - check out http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+sleep

Comment: Perhaps you should rewrite your question: "Is there any method which, if run on the UI thread, would be equivalent to calling `Application.DoEvents()` continuously and repeatedly for a certain amount of time, preferably with a means of restricting the events that run to things like screen updates or the processing of BeginInvoke'd methods?"

Comment: An approach which kinda-sorta works is to show a modal dialog box which includes a timer-tick method that will auto-close it after a specified time.  Be certain to `Dispose` the dialog box after it closes itself, since failure to do so could cause a memory leak.  Unfortunately, while it's possible to jinx things so the box doesn't actually end up being visible, I've not figured out how to avoid having it work consistently cleanly with UI focus.

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory. You say that you don't want to execute any more code and yet at the same time not "freeze the program". What exactly do you suppose that an *unfrozen* program is doing if not *running code*?

Comment: Possibly what you are looking for is in C# 5 the `await Task.Delay(1000);` mechanism?  This means *suspend execution of the current workflow*, then *return control to the caller so it can keep running more code*, and *schedule the remainder of the current workflow as the continuation of the delay task*.

Comment: I want it to continue running code that has been executed before, but not run any more.

Comment: Can you please define "has been executed before" than? Is it just all already JITed code ok to execute, but no other methods can be JITed till pause expires? (this is only explanation I can come up for that phrase, but it is very unlikely what you mean...)

Answer (score 2):

[`Thread.Sleep(int milliseconds)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332371%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

is what you're looking for

Comment: actually, the signature of the method is wrong, as it is Sleep and it receives parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, everything is running on one thread by default. If you want you can create another thread to run a specific piece of code. Then, you can sleep that thread so your app won't freeze.

Check this question out for more information: [How do I run a simple bit of code in a new thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread)

Answer (score 0):

Yeap:

```
Thread.Sleep(milliseconds)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: That pauses all existing code.

Comment: Just in the thread you are running. If you want something else to run, you should do it in a different Thread.

Comment: My program isn't multithreaded, it doesn't need to be (except for this), so this wouldn't work

Comment: The thing is, what you are describing you want makes no sense at all. Code is executed in a thread. If you want to pause your code, you have to pause the thread. if you want for something to white while other code is running, well... that's multithreading. Indeed, if you use Thread.Sleep, you will notice that the rest of the operative system doesn't freeze. That's because the other things are in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is.

```
Thread.Sleep(milliseconds)
```

For example, if you use `Thread.Sleep(5000)` , it will make thread sleep for 5 seconds. Read more @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332371%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Sleep(milliseconds)` should do it for you

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to verify the syntax as I'm just wingin' it, but this will go into a non-blocking loop for the designated amount of time...

```
// Set the wait time
double waitTime = 5.0;

// Get the current time
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

// Check the wait time
while(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds < waitTime)
{
    // Keep the thread from blocking
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

That assumes you're using Windows Forms.  If you're using WPF:

```
//Application.DoEvents();
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { }));
```

Again, you'll want to verify the syntax first...