# C# - Speeding up reading from Excel using OleDB

Tags: c#, excel, listbox

I am trying to read an Excelfile with OleDB in C# and put it into a listbox. I followed a lot of guides and it works! However, it keeps showing the data with a delay of 50 milliseconds. This is very small, but I am making this for some colleagues of mine and I want it to work better and even more smooth i.e. reduce the delay. 
The excel file is not very big, it contains ~840 items so I can imagine it could go faster.

First I will show you my code for filling the data into the listboxes:

```
    const int straatmeubilair = 0;
    const int boomproducten = 1;
    const int dekkenEnBruggen = 2;
    String queryTempCategorie;
private void lbCategorie_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (lbCategorie.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case straatmeubilair:
                queryCategorie = "A%";
                break;

            case boomproducten:
                queryCategorie = "B%";
                break;

            case dekkenEnBruggen:
                queryCategorie = "C%";
                break;
        }

        if (queryTempCategorie != queryCategorie)
        {
            queryTempCategorie = queryCategorie;
            updateTable(dbProductInfo.getData("SELECT DISTINCT [Productfamilie] FROM [Bestelinfo$] WHERE [Pagina] LIKE '" + queryCategorie + "' ORDER BY [Productfamilie] ASC"), lbFamilie, "Productfamilie");
        }
    }

private void updateTable(DataTable tempTable, ListBox tempListbox, String column)
    {
        tempListbox.DataSource = tempTable;
        tempListbox.DisplayMember = column;
    }
```

So when the listbox changes it's index it tries to fill another listbox with a datatable requested from the database. It also has an extra if/else statement to stop it from requesting data when his last request was the same. The request for the data from Excel is shown in the code below.

```
public DataTable getData(String query)
    {
        // Test features
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(testAmount);
        testAmount += 1;
        // Clear the datatable
        Console.WriteLine("CLEARING DATATABLE");
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        // Create the connectionstring
        strConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + databasePathFile + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""";
        // Create adapter
        Console.WriteLine("CREATING ADAPTER");
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        // Create connection
        Console.WriteLine("CREATING CONNECTION");
        connection = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
        // Create the command for the given connection
        Console.WriteLine("CREATING COMMAND");
        command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

        try
        {
            // Open the connection
            connection.Open();
            // Give the command to the adapter
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            // Fill the dateset with the adapter
            adapter.Fill(data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong, contact IT");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close connection
            connection.Close();
            // Dispose of adapter
            adapter.Dispose();
            TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Runtime " + elapsedTime);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Note: The "databasePathFile" at the connectionstring is defined earlier in the program.

I think I'm doing something weird that it keeps giving me a delay. Does anyone have any suggestions? (Something like: "You need to change your method completely" is also ok :P I'm still learning! However I would like to keep this method.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing my two cents, but try running your **getData** function in a separate thread. I'm refering to -> System.Threading.

Usually running your application on multiple threads will make processes run faster and user experience more seamless.

I'll provide a sample code if you are not familiar using threads in C#.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering this quick :) I have never worked with Threading before. Found the standard explanations of MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx). However, if you think your example is better, don't let it stop you! :P

Comment: Actually, I think this article might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread

This way you can create your thread / threads according to your needs. You can figure out the best running time by constantly moving functionality in or out of your thread.

I see that you already monitor your execution time, so that will give you the best indication when you will be getting most performance out of your code.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a look