# Application crashes on when run

Tags: javascript, c#, crash, freeze

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MafiaspilletBot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://mafiaspillet.no/");
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendData();
        }
        private void SendData()
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("brukernavn")[0].SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("passord")[0].SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("login_buton")[0].InvokeMember("click");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            DoKrims();
        }
        private void DoKrims()
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://mafiaspillet.no/kriminalitet3.php");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
}
```

But everytime I run it and fill in the `textBox1` and `textBox2 and submit them throu`gh the application the whole window just stop working. Is there anything in my code that can make this problem or is there anything I can do to get rid of this problem? Also, I've never worked with c#, this is the first I've made and done in c# as I thought it would be fun to learn c#. Anyways the site that is going to be loaded uses a lot of javascript and i couldn't find a way to let the `webBrowser1` use them, so I used `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;` to ignore the error messages.

Comment: Does it stop working for 25 seconds by any chance?

Comment: What is the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: @Sayse Yeah, that can be the problem, but when i used             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); i wanted it to wait 10 seconds before doing the next thing

Comment: You may wish to read [When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are using:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

And this will make your application unresponsive for 25 seconds each time you will execute `button1_Click`. It will happen because it's all handle by one thread. To avoid it try to do `SendData()` in separate thread.

Easy example would be:

```
Thread SendThread = new Thread(SendData);
SendThread.Start();
```

You can try and do a read on threads here [Run simple thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread)

Comment: What i wanted when i used Thead.Sleep i wanted it to wait first 5 second after first .InvokeMember("click"); before doing the DoKrims(); but i cant see to get some timers for that too work