# Find and display images in picturebox

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, picturebox, directory

I need to search a lot of images in different folders. I have this code, but it only searches in a folder, that I specify. Imagine that I could put a menu strip with some folder names, and the user can click on it to search more faster. I can duplicate FormResultadosFotos3000, but I think it's not necessary.
I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
namespace _myprojet
{
    public partial class FormResultadosFotos3000 : Form
    {
        public FormResultadosFotos3000()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void FormFotos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // se pretendermos pesquisar em várias pastas
            List<string> diretorios = new List<string>()
            {@"\\server01\mydir\mydir\3000"};

            // se pretendermos pesquisar as várias extensões
            List<string> extensoes = new List<string>()
    {".jpg",".bmp",".png",".tiff",".gif"};

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Nome e formato do ficheiro (duplo clique para visualizar a imagem)");
            table.Columns.Add("Caminho ( pode ser copiado Ctrl+C )");
            foreach (string diretorio in diretorios)
            {
                var ficheiros = Directory.EnumerateFiles(diretorio, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
                    Where(r => extensoes.Contains(Path.GetExtension(r.ToLower())));

                foreach (var ficheiro in ficheiros)
                {
                    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                    row[0] = Path.GetFileName(ficheiro);
                    row[1] = ficheiro;
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = true;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormPictureBox myForm = new FormPictureBox();
            string imageName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            Image img;
            img = Image.FromFile(imageName);
            myForm.pictureBox1.Image = img;
            myForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Portuguese language

Comment: Visual Studio - It is C#

Comment: Have a look at threading :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread. Keep in mind that all threads access the same drive so there will be a max to the amount of threads you can run parallel.